# URLs not working after Go Daddy Mask Forwarding

Tags: url, mask, forwarding

I have a domain on Go Daddy and Hosting on HOSTEK. when I pointed my subdomain to the project using Go Daddy mask forwarding. my site is loading its Login page appearing nothing else when I try to hit any web route directly I am getting a page expiration error. do you guys know how can fix it?